# Basic Modal is not working on page load php

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

I have jquery plugin but on page load it works but when I integrate it with my php script it seems not to load.I  have check paths but to no success. as soon as the page loads i want the window to show onload check out my code i put in the head tag please excuse the formatting:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>       
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>SimpleModal Basic Modal Dialog</title>
        <meta name='author' content='Eric Martin'
        />
        <meta name='copyright' content='2012 - Eric Martin' />
        <link type='text/css' href='../css/demo.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen'
        />
        <link type='text/css' href='../css/basic.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen'
        />
        <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
                    return false;
                });
                $('#modalContentTest').modal({
                    onShow: function (dialog) {
                        var sm = this;
                        dialog.container.animate({
                            height: 300,
                            width: 300
                        }, 500, function () {
                            sm.setPosition();
                        });
                    }
                });

            };
        </script>
        <style>
            .noTitle .ui-dialog-titlebar {
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
```

....between body tags i have the php script

Comment: Is your modal content being shown within your HTML, or is it being prevented by the content created "between body tags i have the php script".  You need to check that your `#basic-model-content` is definitely being shown.. and between the `body` tags.  Else the code will hove nothing to show...

Comment: My php code is an upload script when i just do a simple echo Hello it works.

Comment: I can not find any js library for Modal, plus why you are using window.onload with $(document).ready

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the combination of window.onload and jquery $(document).ready.

The "ready" method is triggered when the DOMContentLoaded event is triggered (jQuery simulates this on browsers that do not support it), while window.onload triggers when all additional content (css, images) is loaded - which happens afterwards.

So by the time you bind the "ready" event, the event has already been triggered and will not trigger again.

I suggest removing the window.onload wrapper function.

```
            $('#modalContentTest').modal({
                onShow: function (dialog) {
                    var sm = this;
                    dialog.container.animate({
                        height: 300,
                        width: 300
                    }, 500, function () {
                        sm.setPosition();
                    });
                }
            });
           $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
                return false;
            });
```

Here are some details on these [two events](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/06/14/how-javascript-loading-works-domcontentloaded-and-onload/)

Another concern I have is that the id of the declared modal (#modalContentTest) is different from the one you are trying to trigger (#basic-modal-content)

Comment: I need the onload event i removed it and when i loaded the default nothing happened

Comment: Then leave out the $(document).ready event and just trigger the $("#basic-modal-content").modal();

Comment: Am afraid its not working when i just triggered with out the php code it brought out only the box

Comment: can you put the example somewhere we can test drive it? a Static page will suffice - no php needed.